# Get Excel file changes in Dart

Tags: excel, file, dart

I have an excel file that has a lot of data, it could reach to over 5000 rows with at least 5 columns.

What I want is to get the row that is being changed in this file, without having to read the file all over again. Is this possible?

**Extensive explanation of my problem:**

**I have read** the file **in Dart** and the file is open in **Microsoft Excel**, and the user is **making changes to it in Microsoft Excel**. Can I detect in **Dart** which rows are being updated when the user makes a change to the file in **Microsoft Excel**?

I have seen the [excel](https://pub.dev/packages/excel) package but I don't think it can give me what I want

**EDIT:**
I want to apply this on **Windows** Machines

Comment: You may be able to use the `excel` package with [`FileSystemEntity.watch`](https://api.dart.dev/dev/2.9.0-15.0.dev/dart-io/FileSystemEntity/watch.html).

Comment: I read that on windows this  FileSystemEntity.watch only watches directories

Comment: I see then perhaps you can use [`watcher`](https://pub.dev/packages/watcher)'s [`FileWatcher`](https://pub.dev/documentation/watcher/latest/watcher/FileWatcher-class.html). This is done via polling system (periodically checks for changes).

Comment: @Apealed thank you, but can I know what exactly has changed, I mean which cell?

Comment: I don't think so. You can compare you'r previous excel vale to the "new" on and then determine the change like that.

Comment: @Apealed Yes that would work but it's so inefficient because I might have more than 25000 cells. Thank you

Comment: Correct. It does not seem like there is an efficient way with dart. Perhaps you can write a VBA script for the excel file (that listens to changes) and it can write to some output of the changes. Not sure how much more efficient that would be and it would also require adding the script per excel workbook